# Moved python installation, updated path, "unable to create process using"

Tags: python, python-3.x, path, python-3.11

I moved my python3 installation from C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python to D:\Programs\Python.

Obviously I couldn't call it anymore so I changed the path with the new location.
However I still cannot use python.

When I type "py --version" I get
Unable to create process using 'C:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe  --version':  The file cannot be found (translated so it might not be that exactly).

Since I changed the path, when I call py in the terminal it should fetch it from the new location.
I restarted my PC.

Question : After moving your python installation, which steps have to be done to be able to call again python in the terminal?

Thanks

Comment: I recommend you uninstall python and install it again. It's not about moving the python.exe to another folder, it has a lot of files linked to a directory and they all have to be linked correctly. Next time go to the programs and features tool in Windows and modify python from there.